# PrimeNG - selecting and unselecting rows from different mouse clicks

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

On a p-table, using context menu and p-table row selection (single mode) in primeng, both clicks seem to behave independently. 
When I right click on a table the row is selected, and right clicking on other rows deselects it, however the left click will also do this behaviour without deselecting the right click's selection (if right click then left click). I tried using the OnRowUnselect but it does not seem to work between right and left.

```
<ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
    <tr>
        <th *ngFor="let col of columns" [pSortableColumn]="col.field">
            {{col.header}}
            <p-sortIcon [field]="col.field"></p-sortIcon>
        </th>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
    <tr  [pContextMenuRow]="rowData" [pSelectableRow]="rowData">
        <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
           {{col.field.includes('_dt')?  (rowData[col.field] | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd' : 'GMT+5'):rowData[col.field]}}
        </td>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
<ng-template pTemplate="summary" let-rowData>
    <div style="text-align:left">
        <button type="button" pButton icon="pi pi-plus" (click)="showDialogToAdd()" label="Ajouter"></button>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: I have the same Problem, did you find any solution?

Comment: no but i did manage to do something similar with selecting and unselecting row events and boolean flags. works only partially because you can have a state where both records are selected.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your response. I dont no why nobady can answer this question, because for me that is a common case.

Comment: If i add contextMenuSelectionMode="joint" to my table, it semse to work. But if i right clicked on a row, the selection will not look like the normal selection. For me that is the best alternative.